# MultiLine RegEx for blocks of text beginning with digits

Tags: ruby, regex

I have text that looks like this:

```
8    (10.0.0.1, 224.0.255.36) in e3/2 (e3/2), cnt=0
     Sparse Mode, RPT=0 SPT=1 Reg=0 L2Reg=0 RegSupp=0 LSrc=0 LRcv=0
     upstream neighbor=11.22.44.55
     num_oifs = 1
     L3 (HW) 1: tag e4/19(VL804)
     Flags (0x000280a1)
        sm=1 ssm=0 fast=1 slow=0 leaf=0 prun=0 frag=0 tag=1 needRte=0 msdp_adv=0
     age=0 fid: 8079 mvid:      3 
9    (*, 224.0.255.118) RP 11.22.33.44, in e3/2 (NIL), cnt=0
     Sparse Mode, RPT=1 SPT=0 Reg=0 L2Reg=0 RegSupp=0 LSrc=0 LRcv=0
     upstream neighbor=11.22.44.55
     num_oifs = 2
     L3 (SW) 1: tag e4/19(VL804)
     L3 (SW) 2: tag e4/20(VL805)
     Flags (0x002200a0)
        sm=1 ssm=0 fast=0 slow=0 leaf=0 prun=0 frag=0 tag=1 needRte=0 msdp_adv=0
     age=0 fid: none mvid: none 
10   (10.0.0.1, 224.0.255.118) in e3/2 (e3/2), cnt=0
     Sparse Mode, RPT=0 SPT=1 Reg=0 L2Reg=0 RegSupp=0 LSrc=0 LRcv=0
     upstream neighbor=11.22.44.55
     num_oifs = 0
     Flags (0x000280a1)
        sm=1 ssm=0 fast=1 slow=0 leaf=0 prun=0 frag=0 tag=1 needRte=0 msdp_adv=0
     age=0 fid: 80c9 mvid:    182 
11   (*, 224.2.254.32) RP 11.22.33.44, in e3/2 (NIL), cnt=0
     Sparse Mode, RPT=1 SPT=0 Reg=0 L2Reg=0 RegSupp=0 LSrc=0 LRcv=0
     upstream neighbor=11.22.44.55
     num_oifs = 1
     L3 (SW) 1: tag e4/19(VL804)
     Flags (0x002200a0)
        sm=1 ssm=0 fast=0 slow=0 leaf=0 prun=0 frag=0 tag=1 needRte=0 msdp_adv=0
     age=0 fid: none mvid: 
474  (*, 224.0.254.114) RP 11.22.33.44, in e3/2 (NIL), cnt=0
     Sparse Mode, RPT=1 SPT=0 Reg=0 L2Reg=0 RegSupp=0 LSrc=0 LRcv=0
     upstream neighbor=11.22.44.55
     num_oifs = 0
     Flags (0x002200a0)
        sm=1 ssm=0 fast=0 slow=0 leaf=0 prun=0 frag=0 tag=1 needRte=0 msdp_adv=0
     age=0 fid: none mvid: none
```

I want to return a match for each block. I'm using Ruby.

I've tried regex like this, but it's not working right:

```
(^\d+[\S\s].*?)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to match the whole block?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do, but if you just want to split the whole text into an array, then:

```
your_string.split(/(?<=.)(?=^\d)/)
```

or more carefully,

```
your_string.split(/(?<=.)(?=^\d+\s+)/)
```

The problem with your regex is that, by default, `.` does not match multi-lines, which include "\n". In order to do so, you need to put `m` after your regex: `/  /m`.